# Finding the cell value from another sheet basing on row/column index

Tags: excel

I use Excel 2013.

I have two sheets: `work_hours` and `tasks`:

```
#work_hours!
    A            B        C            D
1   Task         Hours    Cost (sum)   Cost per hour
2   Task1        5
3   Task2        3
4   Task1        2

#tasks!
    A            B            C
1   Name         Cost (sum)   Description
2   Task1        500          Desc1
3   Task2        1000
```

I want to fill the `work_hour:C` column (*Cost (sum)*) **automatically** (by formula).

The value of each cell (e.g. C2, C3, C4... let's call it **MY CELL**) should be:

```
**MY CELL** value should be: The value of cell ($B;x) from `tasks` sheet, 
where x is the row index in `tasks` where name (A column) match the name
from the row of **MY CELL**.
```

So in my example the formula should produce:

```
#work_hours!
    A            B        C            D
1   Task         Hours    Cost (sum)   Cost per hour
2   Task1        5        500
3   Task2        3        1000
4   Task1        2        500
```

I know that the row index from `tasks` can be found by:

```
=MATCH(C2;tasks!A:A;0)
```

Which returs `2`.

**But how to change that formula, so it will return `500` (value of `B` column in `tasks` with the same row index)?**

Comment: use index with match being second argument

Comment: And I think you want to match A2 not C2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `VLOOKUP` like this

`=VLOOKUP(C2;tasks!A:B;2;0)`

That will match C2 with column A in Tasks and then return the value from the second column

Comment: Thanks :) I finally used `=INDIRECT("tasks!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(A2;tasks!A:A;0);3))`, but your solution is good :)

Comment: OK, but why that way? VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH would be preferable in most cases

Comment: Just because I wasn't aware of VLOOKUP ;)